# Why is EF Core 2.0 seemingly generating the wrong value?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, auto-generate

I'm using the InMemoryDatabase for my unit tests. In my unit test I add some data to my derived DbContext via `_context.Add(new Item(){Description="desciption"}).`

In my test, I'm adding a new entity. I get a key conflict.

My repository method

```
//Before this method runs _context.Item already has one Item with Id = 1 which I set up in my unit test.
public async Task CreateItem(ItemDM dm){
    Item newItem = new Item(){Name = dm.RelatedItem.Process.Name}; //Id is zero here
    _context.Add(newItem); // The Error happens here
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The error I'm getting is "same key value for {"id"} is already being tacked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached."

It was my understanding that EF Core would increment the Id appropriately but that seems to not be the case.

Comment: We need your settings of ef, the db context, if it's db or code first, and at best, an [mcve]. We can't do magic, and we will definitely not guess blindly what the problem is ;)

Comment: Its tough because the code is on a different computer :/ -- I'll try to update is some...

Comment: if database first and testing with in-memory then it will not auto increment key as that info lives in the actual database. Is there any attribute on the entity that would indicate that the key is auto incremented?

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks, okay - Do you know if SQLite would fix my issue?

Comment: Possible. `The SQLite provider itself is another relational database provider but we can take advantage of SQLite in-memory mode. The nice thing about this provider is that we get the full behavior of a relational database, with the benefits of the running in-memory.` But you have not provided enough details for me to say definitively that the id will auto increment.

Comment: @Nikosi I looked at the fluent code in OnModelCreating() to see if they were being setup and I looked for data annotations in the model classes. The keys aren't being explicited configured to automatically generate. I was under the impression that Primary Keys that are of type int auto generate. I got that from -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#conventions

Comment: If you look at the warns in the same article you linked. `ValueGeneratedOnAdd() just lets EF know that values are generated for added entities, it does not guarantee that EF will setup the actual mechanism to generate values.`

Comment: @Nkosi Could you provide a link that affirms what you stated when you said, "if database first and testing with in-memory then it will not auto increment key as that info lives in the actual database."

Comment: Read this article https://www.scottbrady91.com/Entity-Framework/Entity-Framework-Core-In-Memory-Testing. I'm still looking for official doc

Comment: Official doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory

Comment: not a permanent solution. but does `_context.SaveChanges()` at the start of the function as well help?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane It prevents the error happening when calling `_context.Add()` but the line below it now errors with "An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 1" -- I'm currently baffled on why that caused the error to go away when call `.Add()`

Comment: try replacing the add with `_context.Add(new Item(){Name = dm.RelatedItem.Process.Name});`

Comment: @Nkosi I just read the article you provided and I saw nothing about database first and auto incrementing... I didn't see anything in the microsoft docs either

Comment: The question is how did you add the Item with Id = 1 initially. I suspect you provided Id = 1 manually rather than letting EF auto generate it. In such case the auto generator will generate 1 the first time used, hence the duplicate key. Don't seed the data with  hardcoded values for auto generated columns, let EF (or database) always generate them.

Comment: @IvanStoev That's what I was doing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this was happening is because I was adding my entities with a hardcoded value. E.g. `.Add(new Item(){Id = 1})` My assumption is that the auto-generating capability would recognize this and update accordingly. I was wrong.

Props to @Ivan Stoev for the information provided in the comments